# How to make QComboBox popup transparent

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make the `QAbstractItemView` in my `QComboBox` transparent in `PyQt5`. I want to be able to see the main widget behind it, and have control over the opacity.

I've tried what I've seen on another post.

```py
comboBox.view().parentWidget().setWindowOpacity(0.5)
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I also have tried:

```py
comobBox.setStyleSheet('QAbstractItemView{background: transparent; background-color: rgba(200,0,0,0}')
```

still nothing.

Here is an example of the transparency I'm looking for in my QComboBox dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't complete.

You should put a ***Minimal Working Example***.
Anyhow, maybe this is the thing you're looking for?

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

The [`QWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) class has a method `.setAttribute` which allows to modify some properties of the widget. There are many attributes that you can set to your widget that may behave the way you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't provide the look I'm going for.  I've added an image example of what I mean. It's not a qcombobox but the transparency is what I'm after. I won't have an example, as I'm not asking about specific code but a broad concept of PyQt.